# Column Error in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I used a CASE function to create a new column. When I try to use the new column I get  the following column error:

> no such column: price_each

```
SELECT  o1.orderid,
        productid,
        shipcountry,
        quantity,
        unitprice,
        discount,
        case
            WHEN discount > 0
                THEN unitprice - (unitprice * discount)
            ELSE unitprice
        END AS price_each,
        quantity * price_each AS ttl
    FROM orders o1 JOIN OrderDetails o2
        ON o1.orderid = o2.orderid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this out:

```
SELECT  o1.orderid,
        productid,
        shipcountry,
        quantity,
        unitprice,
        discount,
        case
            WHEN discount > 0
                THEN unitprice - (unitprice * discount)
            ELSE unitprice
        END AS price_each,
        quantity * (SELECT price_each) AS ttl
    FROM orders o1 JOIN OrderDetails o2
        ON o1.orderid = o2.orderid
```

Or can be done as:

```
SELECT ord_id,productid,shipcountry,quantity,unitprice,discount,price_each, (price_each * quantity) AS ttl FROM 
(SELECT  o1.orderid AS ord_id,
        productid,
        shipcountry,
        quantity,
        unitprice,
        discount,
        case
            WHEN discount > 0
                THEN unitprice - (unitprice * discount)
            ELSE unitprice
        END AS price_each
    FROM orders o1 JOIN OrderDetails o2
        ON o1.orderid = o2.orderid)
AS VR_table
```